# How to make code for boundary value problem?

Tags: boundary-condition-at-infinity, coding-style, mathematica-online, differentials

I am trying to make graphs given by using this code but I failed. Please correct this code.

```
\[CurlyPhi]1=0.4; \[Rho]s=5200; Cs=670; \[Rho]b=890; Cb=686.2; k1=6;
Knf=0.126; Pr=1; Sc=0.5; S1=1.2; S2=0.1; \[Lambda]=0.1; Nt=0.5;
Nb=0.3; S=0.2; K1=0.8; Fr=1.3;

A1=1/(1-\[CurlyPhi]1)^(25/10);
A2=((1-\[CurlyPhi]1)+\[CurlyPhi]1*\[Rho]s*Cs/\[Rho]b*Cb)/10^5;

eq1=A1*F'''[\[Eta]] + A2*(F''[\[Eta]] + (F'[\[Eta]])^2)-A1*F'[\[Eta]] - A2*Fr*(F'[\[Eta]])^2 + S2*Exp[-S1 \[Eta]] == 0;
eq2=Knf*\[Theta]''[\[Eta]] + A1*Pr*F[\[Eta]] \[Theta]'[\[Eta]]+Pr*Nt  
  (\[Theta]'[\[Eta]])^2 + Nb*Pr*\[Theta]'[\[Eta]]*\[CurlyPhi][\[Eta]] == 0;
eq3=\[CurlyPhi]''[\[Eta]] - Sc*F[\[Eta]]*\[CurlyPhi]'[\[Eta]] + Nt/Nb \[Theta]''[\[Eta]] - K1*\[CurlyPhi][\[Eta]] == 0;

bcs1={F[0]==S, F'[0] == 0, F'[5] == 1};
bcs2={\[Theta]'[0] == -0, \[Theta][5] == 0};
bcs3={\[CurlyPhi]'[0] = [![=-1, \[CurlyPhi][5] == 0};

b1=NDSolve[{eq1, eq2, eq3, bcs1, bcs2, bcs3},
  {F[\[Eta]], F'[\[Eta]], \[Theta][\[Eta]], \[Theta]'[\[Eta]], \[Phi][\[Eta]], \[Phi]'[\[Eta]]}, {\[Eta], 0, 4}];
```

```
Needs["PlotLegends`"]
Plot[Evaluate[F'[\[Eta]]/.b1], {\[Eta],0,4}, PlotRange->All,
  PlotStyle->{{Dashing[{solid}], Black}}, PlotLegend->{"\[Lambda]=0.1", "\[Lambda]=0.2", "\[Lambda]=0.3", "\[Lambda]=0.5","\[Lambda]=0.7"}, LegendSize->{0.4,0.45},
  LegendPosition->{-0.01,0.1}, PlotMarkers->Automatic, LegendShadow->False,
  Frame->True,Axes->False, FrameLabel->{Style["\[Eta]",Italic, Black], Style["F'(\[Eta])", Italic, Black]}]][1]][1]
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: If you post code with Greek letters on this site of the form "\[<letter>]", you need to escape the backslash, otherwise it gets dropped. So use a double backslash, i.e. "\\[<letter>]". There's a typo in bcs3 between the "==" signs for t. The code for eq2 didn't parse correctly; there was no operator after Pr*Nt and the following line. When you post code on the web, it's a good idea to copy it back over to your own machine and execute in with a fresh kernel (i.e. after a Quit) to verify other users will be able to run it without problems.

Comment: Looking at your image, I guessed that the operator at the end of the line was a "*", so that's what I added. As for the plot, you also seem to have an extraneous [1][1] appended to your Plot command which I removed. 
 Since you're not doing any dashing, you don't need the PlotStyle, which is incorrect anyway; for solid dashing, it's Dashing[{}]. The package you're using is built in as of version 9.0. See Compatibility/tutorial/PlotLegends in the documentation to see what to use , instead. However, that's beside the point, because legends are used to label distinct curves,

Comment: and you're only plotting one.  Lambda is a fixed constant, so unless you plan to generate a table of plots, it makes no sense to try to label them.

Answer (score 1):

I made the following changes. I commented out lambda, since you need to make a table of solutions. There was a problem with Pr*Nt* being split across lines, so I added an explicit multiplication. The "==" on bcs3 had extra characters which I deleted. And your original plot had [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UemED.png) at the tail end, which is not legal syntax, so I removed it. While trying to set up to run a series of different lambda values, I noticed that lambda was absent from your equations. Looking at the screenshot of the paper, it looks like it needs to  multiply one of the A1 terms, so I changed eq1, passing it in as a parameter and using SetDelayed.

```
nf = 0.126; Pr = 1; Sc = 0.5; S1 = 1.2; S2 = 0.1;(*\[Lambda]=0.1;*)Nt \
= 0.5;
eq2 = Knf*\[Theta]''[\[Eta]] + A1*Pr*F[\[Eta]] \[Theta]'[\[Eta]] + 
    Pr*Nt*(\[Theta]'[\[Eta]])^2 + 
    Nb*Pr*\[Theta]'[\[Eta]]*\[CurlyPhi][\[Eta]] == 0;
bcs3 = {\[CurlyPhi]'[0] == -1, \[CurlyPhi][5] == 0};
eq1[lambda_] := 
  A1*F'''[\[Eta]] + A2*(F''[\[Eta]] + (F'[\[Eta]])^2) - 
    A1*lambda F'[\[Eta]] - A2*Fr*(F'[\[Eta]])^2 + S2*Exp[-S1 \[Eta]] ==
    0;
```

I then set up a list of lambda values and used Table to run NDSolve with these values passed into eq1, and stored the results in indexed variable b1.

```
lambdaValues = {0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.5, 0.7};
Table[b1[i] = 
   NDSolve[{eq1[lambdaValues[[i]]], eq2, eq3, bcs1, bcs2, 
     bcs3}, {F[\[Eta]], 
     F'[\[Eta]], \[Theta][\[Eta]], \[Theta]'[\[Eta]], \[Phi][\[Eta]], \
\[Phi]'[\[Eta]]}, {\[Eta], 0, 4}], {i, 5}];
```

I modified Plot to accept a Table of solutions. The functionality of the PlotLegends package was incorporated into Mathematica 9.0 as built-in functionality. See Compatibility/tutorial/PlotLegends in the documentation to see what to use in place of the package functions. As a general rule, it's a good idea to start with something basic to see if things work before trying to do a fancy plot with lots of options to pretty things up. In that spirit, I removed most of the plot options and just kept the basic PlotLegends command and a few others which look harmless. If you want all the stuff for markers, positioning, shadowing (I'm not sure if shadowing is supported), you're welcome to go through the documentation and figure out how to set this up.

```
Plot[Evaluate[Table[F'[\[Eta]] /. b1[i], {i, 5}]], {\[Eta], 0, 4}, 
 PlotRange -> All, 
 PlotLegends -> {"\[Lambda]=0.1", "\[Lambda]=0.2", "\[Lambda]=0.3", 
   "\[Lambda]=0.5", "\[Lambda]=0.7"}, Frame -> True, Axes -> False, 
 FrameLabel -> {Style["\[Eta]", Italic, Black], 
   Style["F'(\[Eta])", Italic, Black]}]
```

Here's the plot I obtained:

[image]

I can't help but notice that it doesn't resemble the one in the image you posted. I'm afraid you're on your own there. But this is also why you make a simple plot first, before embellishing it too much.